# QTcpSocket чтение данных в другом потоке

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, многопоточность, qt5

Есть класс для работы с оборудованием, который имеет 2 основных метода.

В первом методе выполняются манипуляции с оборудованием в результате которых с помощью QTcpServer принимается соединение от оборудования и получается объект QTcpSocket.

Второй метод осуществляет чтение данных из соединения через созданный QTcpSocket.

В одном потоке - всё работает нормально. Но в общем случае чтение может осуществляться в отдельном треде.

Если пытаться вызывать метод получения данных из другого потока то получаем:

[7432] (Parent is QTcpServer(0x1d5b574), parent's thread is QThread(0x46a920), current thread is QThread(0x1db6250)
[7432] QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread

Библиотеки Qt используются под VS. Кто подскажет, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: то есть, чтение может быть в двух тредах одновременно?

Comment: нет, одновременного чтения не будет, просто реализуется интерфейс для существующего приложения, в котором создание объекта происходит в одном треде, его настройка и вызов управляющих методов в другом, а чтение и обработка данных в третьем...

Comment: тогда Вам нужно правильно передавать сокет между тредами - по его дескриптору. А работать с одним сокетом с разных тредов - так Qt очень не любит.

Comment: т.е. принимать соединение, получать дескриптор сокета и создавать в другом треде сокет по этому дескриптору?

Comment: Да. И в стандартных примерах это есть. Вот только багов будет вагон и тележка

Comment: Спасибо! А про MoveToThread что-нибудь сказать можете? Такой подход не поможет?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, в этом случае он не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться!